# Is the plant-human relationship a form of parasitism or commensalism?

Tags: ecology

We all know that mankind gets a lot of useful products for satisfying its needs from plants. They can be in the form of timber, fruits, oils, resins whatever. The plants don't seem to be benefitted from these actions in anyways rather in some cases, they might instead get hurt(as for wood and timber). Some tribes even live on trees to stay clear from predators.
So, is this relationship a form of parasitism or commensalism?

Comment: This appears to meet this sites criteria for a [homework] question — as such you must demonstrate that you have made a significant effort towards answering the question.  In addition, there are ecological relationships that don't fall into a subcategory of symbiosis ... ———— You might find the material on a site like [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/high-school-biology/hs-ecology/) worth reviewing.

Comment: No, this isn't a homework question. I was reading articles on various ecological relationships and this thought crossed my mind.

Comment: Questions don't have to be homework assigned for a class to be considered homework on this site — please consult the help pages on [Ask] questions effectively on this site, I suggest starting with the [page about homework](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework).

Answer (score -1):

It's a complex study because there are different relationships: wild harvests (mahogany), forestry harvests(douglas fir), agriculture harvests(apples), garden plants (poppies), invasive species.
https://www.agclassroom.org/ok/lessons/upper/symbiosis.pdf

example of how to [dial in GOOGLE searches](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNTR_tVzCgCFsfwrlOZL9spWZgo0-Q%3A1572852276897&ei=NNK_Xfi1NtLQaOTjsMgC&q=commensalism%20paratism%20mutualism%20in%20forestry%20human%20agriculture&oq=commensalism%20paratism%20mutualism%20in%20forestry%20human%20agriculture&gs_l=psy-ab.3...16553.20404..20660...0.2..0.423.3941.0j12j2j3j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j33i10i160j33i10i21j33i10.IykRE-1mA08&ved=0ahUKEwj4n_6pg9DlAhVSKBoKHeQxDCkQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) properly to research narrow topics.. time taken? 2 searches, 35 seconds. *"commensalism paratism mutualism in forestry human agriculture"*

Comment: will answer the same next time.